# Auto fill out this webpage

Tags: c#

I am trying to fill out this form but I am having trouble doing it.
Here is the webpage

[Untitled form](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/viewform?formkey=dDViZjNzeWdPS25XZGFhNjF6Z0NnbGc6MQ#gid=0)

I tried this but it did not work

```
wb.Document.GetElementById("entry_0").InnerText = textBox1.Text;
```

and I am not sure how to click the submit button

Comment: You want to edit a google doc? why not use google's API?

Comment: If I had a dollar for every question that said "I tried it but it didn't work", I could quit my job and use the money to start my own Stack Overflow site, with blackjack and hookers.

Comment: @BradChristie no I just want it to fill it out

Answer (score 0):

```
    IHTMLElementCollection m_hec;

foreach (HTMLInputElementClass he in m_hec)
    {
        if (he.getAttribute("name").ToString() == "FIELD[]")
            if (he.getAttribute("value") != null)
                lstInput.Add(he.getAttribute("value").ToString());
            else
                lstInput.Add("");
    }
```

look [here](http://hintdesk.com/c-auto-fill-in-form-of-website/)